ContentPage Thickness Resource causes app to crash on iOS
I have a ContentPage that defines some Resources. When I try to use a Thickness resources in my page's XAML, it causes my app to crash on iOS.
Here is a sample of the XAML that is not working.
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyNamespace.MyPage"
             Title="My Title">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Thickness x:Key="TestMargin">24,0,24,0</Thickness>
            <Color x:Key="TestColor">Yellow</Color>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <Grid BackgroundColor="{StaticResource TestColor}" RowDefinitions="*, Auto, Auto, *">
        <Grid x:Name="loadingView" Grid.Row="2" Margin="{StaticResource TestMargin}" RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*">
        //snip
        </Grid>
     </Grid>
   </Grid>
</ContentPage>

When I try to run this, the app crashes. I get the following error in the Output Window.
=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x20afdb198):0x20afdb188  c0 03 5f d6 c0 03 5f d6 10 29 80 d2 01 10 00 d4  .._..
INFO: 80 d2 01 10 00 d4  .{......P.......

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at MyNamespace.MyPage:.ctor <0x00110>
      at MyNamespace.App:CreateWindow <0x0001a>
      at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application:Microsoft.Maui.IApplication.CreateWindow <0x001de>
      at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ApplicationExtensions:CreatePlatformWindow <0x001ce>
      at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ApplicationExtensions:CreatePlatformWindow <0x00136>
      at Microsoft.Maui.MauiUIApplicationDelegate:FinishedLaunching <0x0012e>
      at __Registrar_Callbacks__:callback_796_Microsoft_Maui_MauiUIApplicationDelegate_FinishedLaunching <0x000e8>
      at __Registrar_Callbacks__:callback_796_Microsoft_Maui_MauiUIApplicationDelegate_FinishedLaunching <0x000c0>
      at <unknown> <0x00000>
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:xamarin_UIApplicationMain <0x00
The app has been terminated.


If I set the Margin to a constant value (Margin="24,0,24,0") it works. The TestColor resource also works for the Grid background color. This seems to be an issue only affecting the Thickness resource. verything works on Windows and Android.
Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Adding [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Skip)] to my Controller seems to have resolved the issue. But, I am not entirely sure why this is necessary.

After added the code, Does adjusting the value of the margin or changing the color still work?

Yes, with the attribute added to the class, I am able to define, use, and modify the ContentPage Resources defined in my XAML. Without the attribute my app will crash when calling InitializeComponent().

Oddly enough, I put your code into the project and without adding [XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Skip) It works fine on iOS platform and android platform. I read
Disable XAML compilation that this is not officially recommended as it affects the performance of the program, so I'm looking for other ways to solve this problem. You can try not adding the code first and then you can try cleaning up the project, or deleting the obj and bin folders and re-running the project.

I have tried all of the standard "fixes"; (clean, remove bin/obj, restarting everything, etc). None of it worked.

Or you can try creating a new project and copying all the code into the new project to check if the problem still occurs
